# ipn not working with sandbox

Tags: paypal-ipn, sandbox

I wrote a script for paypal IPN because I want to update the database after the payment. I'm not even talking about the script content, because it seems that the script is not called at all !

I decided to simplify and to only write one thing in the script: send me an email.

When I pay the subscription on paypal sandbox, I'm redirected to the return URL I inserted in my button, but it seems that the notify url is not called, as I don't receive the mail I'm supposed to receive...

Any idea why ?
At first I thought it was I was on a local server. But now I'm on a live serveur, and it's the same thing.

May I have your help ?

Thank you

Comment: Really need to see your code to see whats happening @Brian